# Why IDENTITY_INSERT is set at execute or run time and not at parse time?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have used IDENTITY_INSERT in one of my query recently. While reading SQL server documentation for **IDENTITY_INSERT**, http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa259221%28v=sql.80%29.aspx, there is a line which says,

> The setting of SET IDENTITY_INSERT is set at execute or run time and not at parse time.

Curious to understand, why IDENTITY_INSERT is set at run time not at parse time? What would be the impact if it's done in other way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it was done at parse time you wouldn't be able to turn it on for multiple tables in a single batch. As it's handled at runtime you can turn it on and off for multiple tables in a single batch. As you can only enable that setting for one table at a time that's kind of important.

Comment: This doesnt answer the question  'why IDENTITY_INSERT is set at run time not at parse time'. He is in essence asking why doesn't the optimizer blow up when it parses the command instead of blowing up at run time

Comment: Sure it does when you really think about it.  The parser and optimizer don't know the values that might be inserted into the table necessarily, so it can't blow up at optimization, that would blow up at the actual execution when it had to enforce a PK or check constraint definition. The execution would fail, but parsing the statements should pass because that doesn't require actual enforcement of the constraints for data validity.  The optimizer/parser doesn't have to set IDENTITY_INSERT to ON/OFF to validate that the INSERT statement is properly formed in any way.

Comment: your comment answers the question but the answer 'the ability to turn on insert for multiple batches' doesnt really answer the question.

Answer (score -2):

The reason being when you are parsing sql queries you are validating that the sql is correct.

There are several stages to executing a sql query

1) **parser** (where your question is)
     - This stage is where the sql is validated. Think of it as looking at a sentence and saying the structure is correct. You really do not care about the logic of it at this point.

2) **Algebrizer**
     -This is where the sql is bound to underlying sql server objects. Again the optimizer doesn't care about the logic, it just cares that all the objects bind
     -This is also where the Binary tree is formed for the sql 
3) **Exploration**
 - this is where the histographics are collected for the query and the optimizer looks for a good enough plan(again the logic isnt cared about)

4) **Execution**. HERE IS WHERE YOUR LOGICAL ERRORS ARE NOTICED. Hence why you see it at run time and not parse time. Because here the logic is actually tested